# Knockout InProcess Image

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to show an in-progress gif when interacting with the server side calls but I am finding it hard as the browser seems frozen during the ajax call and the progress image is only getting displayed after the ajax call returns.

I have a sample js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saamisolutions/S8TrU/5/)

I tried to simulate a server side call with js fiddle echo, let me know if there is a better way to do that. Also with in the AJAX request just to introduce some delay I have a for loop running.

HTML Code

```
    <ul id="basket-result" data-bind="foreach: model">
    <li>
         <h3 data-bind="text: week"></h3>

        <div data-bind="foreach: games">
            <div data-bind="text: url"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: buttons.load">Load</button>
<img src="http://www.bis.org/img/uploading.gif" alt="uploading" data-bind="visible: isProcessing">
```

JS Code

```
    var getJSONString = function () {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: dataMain,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (msg) {
            result = msg;
        }
    });
    console.log(result);
    console.log('Before TimeOut');
    var x = "delayIt";
    for (var tempi = 0; tempi < 5000000; tempi++) {
        x = x + tempi;
    };
    console.log('After TimeOut');
    return result;
}

var viewModel = {
    model: ko.observable(),
    isProcessing: ko.observable(false),
    buttons: {
        load: function () {
            viewModel.isProcessing(true);
            viewModel.model(getJSONString());
            console.log('what is in view model :' + viewModel.model())
            viewModel.isProcessing(false);
        }
    }
}

$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

To see the progress image in action just comment the line "viewModel.isProcessing(false);" with in the viewmodel.buttons.load function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it frozes because that's what you are telling your ajax call to do, with `async: false`, you are telling your ajax call to stop everything untill it finishes, just remove that line, then if you want to let the user know when it is saved in your server you can use something ike this:

```
var vm = {
isLoading: ko.observable(false),
loadData: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.isLoading(true);
    $.getJSON("/echo/json?json={}&delay=2")
        .success(function () {
        // success!
    })
        .complete(function () {
            // always remove the loading, regardless of load/failure
        self.isLoading(false);
    });
}
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/Uq8VJ/

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798846/adding-a-loading-icon-to-knockout-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at your code and like to understand the URL of $.getJSON. Is it a dummy URL or is it pointing somewhere in the JSfiddle?