# popup for loading not working in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have similar application mentioned this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14799288/1395178). (JSFidle in this answer)
But in my case popup is not shown. but if i put alert then popup will display.

```
 loadData: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.isLoading(true);
        alert('1'); // -> now only popup display.
        $.getJSON("/echo/json?json={}&delay=2")
            .success(function () {
            // success!
        })
            .complete(function () {             
            self.isLoading(false);
        });
```

Detail :
My task is show loading popup when user press Add new record button until data load from service call.

Is there anyway i can trigger alert event but without alert?

Comment: well i faced the similar issue while back but i sorted that out just making my ajax call `async:true` (default) . anything like that in your code . cheers

Comment: @supercool - thank you... that's the reason. you can write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a ajax call is set with `async:false` this may effect displaying popup for loading .

So do make your ajax call `async` to `true` to display popup .

**Sample ajax :**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  async:true,  // if you don't mention it here by default it sets to true 
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```